# Are mixed disk types possible on a Dell Perc h710p?

Tags: dell, dell-perc

The PERC 710P supports both SAS and SATA disks. I have a single RAID1 set and would like to add a RAID5 set built out of SATA disks for archival use, but I cannot confirm that a configuration like that is possible. Citations requested if possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the [vendor documentation](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=dell%20perc%20h710p%20manual)

Comment: Why not just call Dell support and ask them?

Comment: The documentation only claims to 'support' them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible as long as the drives are not mixed together. In addition, I would reccomend using nearline SAS drives instead of SATA for stability reasons.

Comment: +1 for NLSAS.  Not much more expensive but less likely to cause controller issues.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean mixed on  a controller or mixed in one array? Can I do a raid1 sas and a raid5 nlsas on the same controller?

Comment: Mixed in one array. The controller won't allow you to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Mixed SAS/SATA drives cannot be combined in a single common virtual disk or RAID set, but you can create separate VDs with various types (RAID1 on SAS, and a separate RAID5 on SATA).

Source: Documentation (below), and personal experience in Dell Storage Support.

[H710 User's Guide](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/Common/poweredge-rc-h310_User's%20Guide_en-us.pdf)

Page 9:
"Mixing SAS and SATA drives within a virtual disk is not supported. Also, mixing hard drives and SSDs within a virtual disk is not supported."

I was able to accomplish something similar what it sounds like you're wanting about a week ago; Existing VD on SATA disks, new SAS drives added to a server, and the H710 allows to create a 2nd separate VD on the added drives.