# Mix HDD and SSD in same RAID 1 array

Tags: raid, dell, dell-poweredge, ssd, dell-perc

I have a Dell Poweredge R410 with Perc H200 controller.

I would like to upgrade my 15k RPM arrays with SSD. Both disks are SAS 6Gbps.

- Will it work if I remove 1 of the 2 disks, replace by the SSD, wait for sync then replace the other one ?
- HDD=600GB, SSD=800GB or 400GB.
  If the HDD only has 100GB used, will the controller by smart enough and allow the sync with a 400GB SDD ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot mix drive types in the same array group on PERC/LSI/HP hardware RAID controllers.

This also applies to mixing SATA, SAS and SSD.

[PERC manual](https://serverfault.com/a/604686/13325):

> "Mixing SAS and SATA drives within a virtual disk is not supported.
>   Also, mixing hard drives and SSDs within a virtual disk is not
>   supported."

Comment: You can't mix SATA and SAS but if both are SAS then it should work. You definately can't use a smaller drive though.

Comment: So... you say it should work, @ewwhite says it doesn't.

Comment: [No, SAS SSD and SAS disk won't work together](http://serverfault.com/a/604686/13325).

Comment: Thanks. 
From the H200 manual : https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwids5e4qv_KAhWCWT4KHR7SCXsQFggcMAA&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.dell.com%2FManuals%2Fall-products%2Fesuprt_ser_stor_net%2Fesuprt_dell_adapters%2Fpoweredge-rc-h200_User%27s%2520Guide_en-us.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEYw-FZlmVPsvBUtB36Ofj_AxKrVw&sig2=8JlebN4zaNrAMqysXW1_vw  "SAS, SATA or SSD physical disks cannot be used in the same virtual disk."